# Trying to get an object string to show instead of the key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Trying to display the correct answer (e.g. "easy answer 1") instead of the answer key (eg "easyA"). is there an easy way to access the array bearing in mind that the questions are shuffled in some previous code? or does the array not need to be accessed to get the answer text to show?

Comment: bit hard to tell from your code, or where you mean, but looks like you want: 
 `$("#easy-correct").append(thisEasyQuestion[thisEasyQuestion.cor]);`

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` stacksnippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure without working code snippet, but try something like that:
Assuming `thisEasyQuestion` is your question object
and `thisEasyQuestion.cor` is pointing to the identifier of the correct answer,
 then `thisEasyQuestion[thisEasyQuestion.cor]` would point to the actual answer.

```
$('.easy-answer-button').on("click", function() {
            const chosenAnswer = this.id;
            if (chosenAnswer == thisEasyQuestion.cor)
           
            {
                $("#easy-correct").append(`${thisEasyQuestion[chosenAnswer]} `);
            }
            else {
                console.log("wrong");
            }
               if (level === 2) {
                $(easyQuestionPage).addClass("hide");
                $("#map-page").removeClass("hide");
            } else {
                    level = level + 1;
                    nextEasyQuestion();
                }
            
      });
```

Basically just changing this line:

```
$("#easy-correct").append(`${thisEasyQuestion[chosenAnswer]}
```

Comment: Getting undefined when using that instead

Answer (score -1):

**do you want this?**

```
cor: shuffleEasyQuestions[level][shuffleEasyQuestions[level].correct]
```